# Capacitor Array Tolerance of Caps in Same Package

Tags: capacitor, tolerance, cmrr, mlcc

Consider an MLCC capacitor array like [CA064X471J5GACTU](https://www.mouser.com/_/?Keyword=CA064X471J5GACTU). Its tolerance is 5% but does this apply to capacitors within the same package?

More specifically, I am wondering if the tolerance of caps within the same package is much better such that it might be used to minimize impact on CMRR in a balanced signal. Meaning I want to use two caps on each line to shunt RF using one array. If they're very close in capacitance, then perhaps CMRR will be better than using separate caps?

Comment: What you're looking for is referred to as the "matching ratio", the variation between parts in the same package. KEMET doesn't seem to specify one for the part you linked--I've never had occasion to use capacitor arrays, but matching ratio is a pretty standard thing to specify for resistor arrays.

Comment: These are not matched well but the inner pair and outer pair might be within 1%. They are also not low ESR in the C0G type ~0.5 ohm I read

Comment: You might expect propoerties dependent on matierial parameters, like tempco, to be well matched automatically. Properties that depend on geometry like capacitance **could** be well matched, but only if the manufacturer has bothered to match them. It may be likely the same footprint has been used for the capacitor section, but has attention been paid to getting the leadout contribution the same?The geometry of the inner two and the outer two is obviously different. If they don't claim a matching tolerance, it would be unwise to expect one.